# Multiple pop up modals close on click away?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple pop-up modals like search, buttons, links and dynamically added elements and I want to close/hide when they're clicked outside their container for each pop-up modals. If there is away of doing for all pop-ups with the same pattern.

Here is a sample code:
[**`jsfiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net/yonashailug/3mfrvxjw/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick you can do is to add a click handler on the document which closes all modals. Then, you can have event handlers on modal containers which call `stopImmediatePropagation`. This will prevent all other handlers from firing and stop the bubble up phase (including the document handler). Therefore, the document handler will fire only when you click outside of the modal container.

```js
function toggleModal(modal) {
  $('.modal:not(' + modal + ')').removeClass('visible');
  $(modal).toggleClass('visible');
}

$('.more-tags, .js-search__form').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$('a.toggle-menu').on('click', function(e) {
  toggleModal('.more-tags');
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$('.js-search__icon').on('click', function(e) {
  toggleModal('.js-search__form');
  $('.js-search').focus();
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation()
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  $('.modal').removeClass('visible');
});
```

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.btn-border {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.25rem;
  color: #777;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

a svg {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  fill: #777;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.more-tags {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
  right: 0;
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  transform: translateY(200%);
  height: 70%;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 37px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  z-index: 9999;
  /* transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.57, 0.67, 1.53); */
  transition: transform 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}

.more-tags.visible {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.search__container svg {
  position: relative;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  fill: #777;
}

.search__form {
  position: fixed;
  background: #fff;
  /* box-shadow: 0px 30px 20px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); */
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 90px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  z-index: 9999;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}

.search__form.visible {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="display:none;">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="icon-search" viewBox="0 0 19 19">
      <title>Search icon</title>
      <path d="M18.86 17.44l-6.69-6.69a6.69 6.69 0 1 0-1.41 1.41l6.69 6.69zm-12-6a4.7 4.7 0 1 1 3.92-2.16l-1.49 1.43a4.63 4.63 0 0 1-2.48.77z" />
    </symbol>
    <g id="filter">
      <path d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z" />
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
    </g>

  </defs>
</svg>

<a href="#" class="toggle-menu btn btn-border">
  <span>More</span>
  <span class="">
                                    <svg class="filter" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve">
                                        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#filter"></use>
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
</a>
<div class="search">
  <div class="search__container">
    <div class="search__icon js-search__icon">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 40 40" enable-background="new 0 0 40 40" xml:space="preserve">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-search"></use>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <form class="modal search__form js-search__form">
      <input type="text" class="form-control js-search" id="search" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="icon icon-close js-icon-close"></div>
      <div class="search__container__result">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">I want to get visa</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">I want to see local communities</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">I want to get citizen services</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="more-tags modal">
  <a href="#" class="js-more-tags-icon-close">
    <span class="icon icon-close"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="more-tags-container">
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-border">
        <span>Hotels</span>
        <span>
                                    <svg class="icon-hotels" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve">
                                        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#hotels"></use>
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-border">
        <span>Supermarkets</span>
        <span>
                                            <svg class="icon-shopping" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve">
                                                <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#shopping"></use>
                                            </svg>
                                        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-border">
        <span>Restaurants</span>
        <span>
                                            <svg class="icon-restaurants" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve">
                                                <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#restaurants"></use>
                                            </svg>
                                        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-border">
        <span>Churches</span>
        <span>
                                            <svg class="icon-book" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve">
                                                <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#book"></use>
                                            </svg>
                                        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-border">
        <span>Charities</span>
        <span>
                                            <svg class="icon-charity" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve">
                                                <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#charity"></use>
                                            </svg>
                                        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-border">
        <span>Meetings</span>
        <span>
                                            <svg class="icon-meeting" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve">
                                                <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#Meeting"></use>
                                            </svg>
                                        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But when you're click on the container itself it hides the container but i don't want to be like that.

Comment: Which container are you referring to? Also, you're toggling the `more-tags` div every time you click on a `a.btn-border` element, including the links in the menu. See the updated snippet

Comment: Thanks for the update. Now it's fine but one problem I have when you click on one element doesn't close another already opened modal.

Comment: Can you give a specific example? Not quite sure which elements and modals you are referring to

Comment: When you click on the search icon and again on more button both opened their containers.

Comment: In that case, you can add a modal class for each element that should be toggle. When you want to toggle a specific modal, use the `not` selector to hide all modals but the one you wish to toggle. See the updated example

Comment: Thanks a lot. now it's great. I know it's annoying question. anyways thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133377/discussion-between-yonas-hailu-and-max-sindwani).